# Databricks Spark connection issue over Simba JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, databricks, azure-databricks, simba

I am trying to connect Spark Databricks from PERL code over Simba JDBC (Databricks recommended way) .For ref this is the JDBC driver: https://databricks-bi-artifacts.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/simbaspark-drivers/jdbc/2.6.17/SimbaSparkJDBC42-2.6.17.1021.zip

So far I managed to setup PERL and all PERL related module config and below issue is nothing to do with PERL which I strongly believe.

I have below code trying to connect Spark Databricks.
Note : 'replaceme' in the password is databricks personaL ACCESS TOKEN.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use DBI;

my $user = "token";
my $pass = "replaceme";
my $host = "DBhost.azuredatabricks.net";
my $port = 9001;
my $url = "jdbc:spark://DBhost.azuredatabricks.net:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=sql/protocolv1/o/853imaskedthis14/1005-imaskedthis-okra138;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=replaceme";  # Get this URL from JDBC data src

my %properties = ('user' => $user, 
                  'password' => $pass, 
                  'host.name' => $host, 
                  'host.port' => $port);

my $dsn = "dbi:JDBC:hostname=localhost;port=$port;url=$url";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, undef, undef, 
          { PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1, jdbc_properties => \%properties })
          or die "Failed to connect: ($DBI::err) $DBI::errstr\n";
my $sql = qq/select * from table/;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
my @row;
while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
 print join(", ", @row), "\n";
}
```

I am ending up below issue and error with SIMBA driver connecting to SPARK THRIFT server as Authentication issue.

```
failed: [Simba][SparkJDBCDriver](500164) Error initialized or created transport for authentication: Invalid status 21
Also, could not send response: com.simba.spark.jdbc42.internal.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed). at ./perldatabricksconntest.pl line 18.
```

The logger recorded below Java stack trace:

```
[Thread-1] 05:40:16,718 WARN  - Error
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][SparkJDBCDriver](500164) Error initialized or created transport for authentication: Invalid status 21
Also, could not send response: com.simba.spark.jdbc42.internal.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed).
        at com.simba.spark.hivecommon.api.HiveServer2ClientFactory.createTransport(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.spark.hivecommon.api.ServiceDiscoveryFactory.createClient(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.spark.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCCommonConnection.establishConnection(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.spark.spark.core.SparkJDBCConnection.establishConnection(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.spark.jdbc.core.LoginTimeoutConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.spark.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.spark.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
        at com.vizdom.dbd.jdbc.Connection.handleRequest(Connection.java:417)
        at com.vizdom.dbd.jdbc.Connection.run(Connection.java:211)
Caused by: com.simba.spark.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][SparkJDBCDriver](500164) Error initialized or created transport for authentication: Invalid status 21
Also, could not send response: com.simba.spark.jdbc42.internal.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed).
        ... 11 more
```

Also as per SIMBA JDBC connector document I have tried NO authentication mode, Username , Username / Password none of them working .

So wonder where is the Authentication issue here in transport layer . Note I already have created token and mentioned that in password section while initiating  jdbc:spark call .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate [personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/authentication) and put it instead of the `replaceme` string in the JDBC url? After that you don't need to specify `user` & `password` fields in the `%properties`.

Comment: when I mean 'replaceme' I did generate the DB personal access token(as per documentation) and put that alphanumeric long string and that is how the code is now. Unfortunately not working.

Comment: hmmm, really strange - I did use JDBC this week, but from Java, and all worked just fine.

Comment: not only this I used simple way to connect Databricks cluster from SQLWorkbench with no help and error reported on certificates .